# jQuery conflict with Edge Animate

Tags: jquery, adobe-edge

I've made a banner with Edge Animate 2.0.1 that is supposed to run on a number of sites. They don't allow iframes, so I've given them the following code:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"    src="http://ads.gobrave.s3.amazonaws.com/fortnox-januari-2014/banner_new_other_format_edgePreload.js"></script>
   <div id="Stage-Fortnox-2" class="EDGE-43189913" data-clicktracker=""></div>`

It worked great when testing it on my own site. But then I got the following mail from their support crew:
"There's an ad that highjacks the jquery object, which causes the page to crash every 10th-15h reload (when the ad is fetched)."

I've tried to add the following code in the top of _edgePreload.js:

> jq_old = jQuery.noConflict(true);

And then resetting the jQuery object at the bottom of the file:

```
jQuery = jq_old;
```

But this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any suggestions?